# What is the difference between these two types of declarations and where to use what?

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9

what is the difference between

```
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator = { UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view) }()
```

and

```
var animator : UIDynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a closure. It might me handy to create constant objects using closure when you need to adjust some of the object properties after creating it. Like following:

```
private static let formatter : NSDateFormatter = {
    let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
    fmt.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    fmt.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    return fmt
    }()
```

The second one is a normal declaration. It should be used in most cases.